# Design impressive table and search box

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I want to place a `Search Text Box` in table like in attached image.

I am using this example for my table [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nI26FKpdiMpdm1Eu1Cus?p=preview), but this is not according to my requirement. Need some css restyling to improve...

In above example you can see that search box is not inside table, and css is not impressive, **I need table like following image**. Here seach box is inside table.  For my table design I am using **angularjs**

[image]

```js
// Instantiate the app, the 'myApp' parameter must 
// match what is in ng-app
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Create the controller, the 'ToddlerCtrl' parameter 
// must match an ng-controller directive
myApp.controller('ToddlerCtrl', function ($scope) {
  
  // Define an array of Toddler objects
  $scope.toddlers = [
    {
      "name": "Toddler One",
      "birthday": "1/1/2011",
      "happy": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Toddler Two",
      "birthday": "2/2/2011",
      "happy": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Toddler Three",
      "birthday": "3/3/2011",
      "happy": false
    }
  ];
  
});
myApp.directive('multiwareswitchitem', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              value: '='
          },
          template: '<div>{{value.name}}  <div><small> Birthday {{value.birthday}} </div></small></div>'
      };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.7" data-semver="1.2.7" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
    .switchBox td {
        padding-right: 64px;
    }
    .switchBox .entBox {
        overflow:auto;height:10em; width:300px; border:1px solid #cccccc;  border-radius: 4px;float:left; box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 10px;focus: {border-color: #66afe9;};
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;

    }
    .switchBox .entBox div:hover {
        background-color: #3875D7;
    }
    .switchBox .entBox:focus {
      border-color: #66afe9;
      outline: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    }
    .switchBox .eBox2.entBox {
        background-color: #444;
    }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="ToddlerCtrl">
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>All Toddler*  
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Search City" ng-model="search.name">
           </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="switchBox">
            <td>
                <div class="entBox">                        
                    <multiwareswitchitem ng-repeat="item in toddlers |filter: search" value="item">       
                    </multiwareswitchitem>                        
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can i suggest you to use this library? [jqWidgets - jqxListBox](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxlistbox/index.htm)

Comment: @a.ndrea yes,  it looks impressive, But with searchbox inside table, I am using angularjs

Comment: Just scroll at left side and you'll find different functionality. Look up for "Filtering" or "Remote Search". There is an angularjs integration system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your own style as much as you need. I have edited your js fidler. you may like this-

[image]

html -

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="ToddlerCtrl" class="toddler-search-container">
  <label>All Toddler*</label>
  <div class="search-container">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Search City" ng-model="search.name">
    <div class="entBox">                        
                <multiwareswitchitem ng-repeat="item in toddlers |filter: search" value="item">       
                </multiwareswitchitem>                        
            </div>  
  </div>

</div>
```

Css Style -

```
body {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.toddler-search-container{
  width:100%;
  display:table;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:calibri;
  position:relative;
}

.toddler-search-container label{
  font-weight:bold;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  margin-right:5px;
  position:relative;
}

.toddler-search-container .search-container{
  float:left;
  background:#ffffff;
  border:solid 1px #5897FB;
  display:table;
  padding:6px;
  border-radius:4px;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 5px #5897FB;
}

.toddler-search-container .search-container input{
  border:solid 1px #aaaaaa;
  margin:2px 0;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px 2px #F3F3F3;
  padding:5px 5px;
}

.toddler-search-container .search-container .entBox{
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery.datatable.js with angular.data table.js ...it has good table template and have a search box which gives instant result...you can use that...I could not add code snippet due to poor net connectivity...but I vl love to give suggestion if u implement it